# How can i save feature extraction as tuple from .wav file to excel?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, wav, feature-extraction

I'm using following code, But my fbank_feat is tuple and i can't save feature extraction in excel file (in line 28 - df).

```
from pathlib import Path
from python_speech_features import fbank
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


path = Path('/home/narges/dataset/dataset-CV-16kHz-128kbps/train/').glob('**/*.wav')
wavs = [str(wavf) for wavf in path if wavf.is_file()]
wavs.sort()
print(wavs)

number_of_files=len(wavs)
spk_ID = [wavs[i].upper() for i in range(number_of_files)]
spk_sent = [wavs[i] for i in range(number_of_files)]


for i in range(number_of_files):
    (rate, sig) = wavfile.read(wavs[i])



fbank_feat=fbank(sig, rate, winlen=0.06, winstep=0.01, nfilt=26, nfft=512, lowfreq=0, highfreq=rate/2, preemph=0.97, winfunc=np.hamming)
print(fbank_feat)

df = pd.DataFrame('fbank_feat')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('dataset.xlsx', engine='xlsxWriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'feat1')
writer.save()
```